# Get and show json data from website's APIs in Delphi XE

Tags: python, json, delphi, httprequest, delphi-xe

I am trying to re-write a piece of code I wrote in Python to Delphi. 
The Python code is:

```
url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
lastvalue = data['last']
```

And this is enough to assign to the variable called "lastvalue" the value that I get from bitstamp's API.

I would like to do the same thing with delphi (I am using delphi XE6). I tried to find some answer here, and I am able to connect to the bitstamp's website and to get the full string, by doing this:

```
function GetURLAsString(const aurl:  string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    lHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
    Result := lHTTP.Get(aURL);
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And then I call this function with this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
mydata : string;

begin
mydata := GetURLAsString('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
Label1.Text := mydata;
end;
```

I'm stuck here. I searched a lot but I am not able to figure out how can I assign to Label1.Text just the value assigned to "last".

When I run this I get `{"high": "629.40", "last": "622.00", "timestamp": "1401544416", "bid": "621.99", "vwap": "617.47", "volume": "15147.30475739", "low": "602.26", "ask": "622.00"}` assigned to Label1.Text.

I hope I was able to explain the question. I am really stuck in this point for some days, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You need a JSON parser library, such as SuperObject.

Comment: On another note, how is that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` getting free'd?

Comment: @JerryDodge the owner is passed in the constructor, so it should be freed with the TIdHTTP instance

Comment: @JerryDodge: or the JSON parser that comes with XE6: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/JSON

Comment: @mjn Ahh, missed that because I personally tend not to rely on that, I always make sure to free things myself. I've seen problems with that before.

Comment: @Remy True, except this question's tagged `delphi-xe` which there may have been one in that version too, but `SuperObject` was just one example of a library.

Comment: @Jerry: TJSONObject was introduced in Delphi 2010.

Comment: @Bruce I'm not saying there wasn't, I'm just saying there's multiple possible solutions.

Comment: @Jerry: Understood.  I was just clarifying on your comment "there may have been one in that version".  There was.

Comment: thank you for all the answers. I will use the JSON parser that comes with XE6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DBXJSON` unit to parse the JSON response.

Try this sample

```
var
  LJsonObj   : TJSONObject;
  LJsonValue : TJSONValue;
begin
    mydata := GetURLAsString('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');
    LJsonObj    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(mydata),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
     LJsonValue := LJsonObj.Get('last').JsonValue;
     Label1.Text:= LJsonValue.Value;
  finally
     LJsonObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I noticed that in delphi XE6 the DBXJSON unit is called System.JSON; at first I added to the uses part "DBXJSON", which is not correct for the last version of Delphi; I just want to write it here in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: I have just a small issue left: if I want to do the same thing with this website: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json, how can I get the "rate" value under USD, which is (if I am not wrong) in an object inside another object?

Answer (score 2):

With the SuperObject free open source JSON parser, the code would be:

```
var
  Mydata: string;
  MyObject: ISuperObject;
  Last: string; 
begin
  ... // perform GET request and store response in Mydata

  MyObject := SO(Mydata);
  Last := MyObject.S['last'];

  ...
```

or shorter:

```
  // get the JSON web resource content 
  Mydata := GetURLAsString('...');

  // get the value of the 'last' property of the object
  Last := SO(Mydata).S['last'];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I searched a little and I found that SuperObject does not work on Android; I forgot to mention that I would need this also on mobile devices. I found x-superobject which is for android too. As soon as I'll learn how to add x-superobject to my delphi (yes, I'm a noob, I still have to learn how to install .pas packages), I'll try to use it, it seems much simplier than the native JSON parser.